# How to filter out values inside of a list of lists in pyspark

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, filter, pyspark

I have an rdd containing  lines such as the following

```
[(0, (['componenţa', 'parlamentului:', 'a', 'se', 'vedea', 'procesul-verbal'], ['membership', 'of', 'parliament:', 'see', 'minutes']))]
```

I am trying to filter out the data objects that contain the word "vedea" by using the following :

```
Index_Comb=Index_Ro.join(Index_En).reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)\ # Joining two RDDs into one
                                  .filter(lambda x : "vedea" not in x[1])
```

However the resulting RDD is empty and i don't know why, is there something i am missing in the condition i made?

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I guess in my example something a list like [(0, (['componenţa', 'parlamentului:', 'a', 'se', 'procesul-verbal'], ['membership', 'of', 'parliament:', 'see', 'minutes']))] which will no contain the word vedea, just have trouble selecting the second list for example inside the list, shouldn't it be x[1] or is there something i am missing?

Comment: check: `rdd.mapValues(lambda x: tuple([e for e in d if e != 'vedea'] for d in x)).collect()`

Answer (score 1):

For **`spark2.4`**, using **`Dataframes`**, you can use ***higher order functions*** **`transform and filter`** to filter on array of arrays or other nested data structure.

```
#sample dataframe
df.show()
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|list                                                                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[componenţa, parlamentului:, a, se, vedea, procesul-verbal], [membership, of, parliament:, see, minutes]]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

df.withColumn("list", F.expr("""transform(list,x-> filter(x, y-> y!='vedea'))""")).show(truncate=False)

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|list                                                                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[componenţa, parlamentului:, a, se, procesul-verbal], [membership, of, parliament:, see, minutes]]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In this case that you want to **`remove`** **`any list`** **`inside a list`** that contains the word *`'vedea'`*, you could use **`filter`** and **`array_contains`**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("list",\
F.expr("""filter(list,x-> array_contains(x,'vedea')!=True)""")).show(truncate=False)
#+---------------------------------------------+
#|list                                         |
#+---------------------------------------------+
#|[[membership, of, parliament:, see, minutes]]|
#+---------------------------------------------+
```